# Load big text (a lot of lines) file to listBox

Tags: c#, text, listbox, load

How load big text file (12150001 lines) to listBox?
Application is not responsible.
My code:

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\xxx\Documents\xxx.txt";
listBoxXYZ.DataSource =  File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
```

Or:

```
                    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = System.IO.File.OpenText(fileName))
                {
                    List<string> _list = new List<string>();

                    String input;
                    while ((input = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        _list.Add(input.ToString());
                    }
                    listBoxXYZ.DataSource = _list;
                    sr.Close();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The ListBox component is just not designed to handle that amount of data.
Beside, you will also have a huge amount of memory used, just for the listbox.

Also the user probably won't be able to do anything with a listbox of that size.
I think you should reconsider your usecase and look for a better component, perhaps with lazy loading as well.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion.
How could I solve it? :)

Comment: What is the content of the file, what should the user do with the displayed 12000000 rows/lines?

Comment: It is generated content - list of vehicle registration plates.